# async def and call stack

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

When using asyncio with Python 3.6, if one function deep in the callstack is async, do I need to make the whole stack async and put await at every call?
For example I have:

```
class FileDataSource:  
    def getData(self):  
        return pd.read_csv('/some/file')

class SocketDataSource:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.reader, self.writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection(host, port)

    async def getData(self):
        data = await self.reader.readuntil(b'\n\n')
        return data

def func1(datasource):
    func2(datasource)

def func2(datasource):
    func3(datasource)

def func3(datasource):
    datasource.getData()

def main(host, port):
    if host is None:
        func1(FileDataSource())
    else:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        for timeout in range(1, 60):
            loop.call_later(timeout, func1(SocketDataSource(host, port)))
        loop.run_forever()
```

1. In the above example, do I need to make the whole call stack of func1 / 2 / 3 as async and await on all of them? (I am afraid answer is yes)
2. Can I interchangeably pass FileDataSource and SocketDataSource to func1 or do I need to change the whole call hierarchy based on async vs non-async calls?
3. What would be the best way to design something like this which can run as a server or a batch?

Thanks a lot in advance for all help!

Comment: Have you tried running the code and gotten an error?

Comment: Yes - it runs when I make func[123] async and await on all of them. I am curious if there is a way not to do it - i.e. make getData() interface the same whether it is reading a file or socket.

Comment: I am on vacation at the moment but going to try it out once back in the office. I will post a comment to conclude the thread. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

> if one function deep in the callstack is async, do I need to make the whole stack async and put await at every call?

The answer depends on what exactly the functions in the call stack do, but most likely yes. `await` affects requires the async function to communicate with its caller - either the awaiter or the event loop driver - in order to ensure suspension/resumption of its execution.

A non-async function can participate in the call stack without awaiting, but then it can only be used to transmit the coroutine object and it cannot examine the data. For example, `func3` could be implemented as either:

```
async def func3(datasource):
    return await datasource.getData()
```

or:

```
def func3(datasource):
    return datasource.getData()
```

But the first function could examine (or log, etc.) the data returned by `getData`, whereas the second one exits immediately and returns the coroutine object which someone else must await.

> Can I interchangeably pass `FileDataSource` and `SocketDataSource` to `func1` or do I need to change the whole call hierarchy based on async vs non-async calls?

Once you make all the functions in the call stack async, you won't be able to pass `FileDataSource`, but that doesn't mean you have to have two separate call hierarchies. Just implement `FileDataSource` as trivially "async" by changing `def getData()` to `async def getData()` (and otherwise leaving the implementation unchanged), and it will work for async usage, provided it doesn't actually block.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I realized that making func[123] async works. However, the whole idea was to hide how the data is received and getData should return actual data whether it comes from file or socket. I am wondering if there is a way to make 'await' actually wait on result and resume execution when socket read is complete.

Comment: @DGandhi *the whole idea was to hide how the data is received and getData should return actual data whether it comes from file or socket* - and you can easily do that, just make `getData` async and in the file case return from it immediately, and in the socket case await from the appropriate stream.

Comment: @DGandhi *I am wondering if there is a way to make 'await' actually wait on result and resume execution when socket read is complete* Of course, that's precisely what it's for! An async `getData` can await [`asyncio.open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) to obtain a pair of streams. It can get data by awaiting the streams' `read` method (or `readline` etc.) as appropriate.